# Предложение смешанного типа: бессоюзная, подчинительная и сочинительная связи

Tags: пунктуация, спп, сложное-предложение, бсп

*Но учти: они [перспективные специальности] постоянно меняются, так что держи ухо востро, следи за трендами — и тогда ты как специалист будешь всегда в цене.*

Корректно ли после двух частей предложения, соединённых бессоюзной связью, присоединять части предложения с подчинительной и сочинительной связями?
Причём 3-я и 4-я части сложного предложения (однородные придаточные, соединённые сочинительной связью), в отличие от 2-й, НЕ поясняют 1-ю часть, а также не являются придаточными ко 2-й части. Они являются придаточными следствия к 1-й и 2-й части в составе блока.

{ [Но... ] : [ ] }, так что ( ) — и ( ).

⠀⠀⠀⠀↑_____________|_____|

И у меня возникли трудности с тем, как однозначно изобразить это при помощи пунктуации.

Обычно центральная связь бессоюзная или сочинительная, а здесь центральная связь подчинительная, а внутри одного из блоков — бессоюзная. Я такого ещё не встречал.

Comment: Что значит при помощи пунктуации?

Comment: Это значит, используя знаки препинания, выразить отношения между частями предложения.

Comment: Я опять вас не понял. Но если вы спрашиваете, о корректности знаков препинания, у вас все верно.

Comment: Я спрашиваю не сколько о корректности знаков препинания, сколько о корректности такого синтаксиса вообще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Но учти: они  постоянно меняются, так что держи ухо востро, следи за трендами — и тогда ты как специалист будешь всегда в цене.**

Перед нами сложное предложение с определенной семантикой, которая вполне понятна. (1) Перспективные профессии меняются. (2) Постоянно изучай  топ-10 самых перспективных профессий, и тогда будешь  в числе востребованных специалистов с высокой зарплатой. Здесь **три  мысли**, но желательно использовать **два основных смысловых блока,** чтобы читатель четко их определил и на письме, и в устной речи.

Каждое  предложение имеет грамматическое значение. Грамматическим значением **сложного** предложения является **выражение смысловых отношений между предикативными частями, входящими в его состав**. Существует три вида связи между частями сложного предложения: **сочинительная, подчинительная, бессоюзная.**

**Что считается корректным?** Корректно выбрать такое сочетание этих связей, чтобы они наилучшим образом выразили семантику предложения (**это единственное условие для сочетания связей, других нет**).

Вернемся к предложению.

**(1) Но учти: (2) они  постоянно меняются, // так что (3) держи ухо востро, (4) следи за трендами — и (5)тогда ты как специалист будешь всегда в цене.**

Два смысловых блока определены ясно. **В первом блоке (1, 2)** используется бессоюзная связь, обозначающая изъяснительные отношения. **Между блоками следственная связь обозначена подчинительным союзом ТАК ЧТО.**

**Второй блок** (3, 4, 5) более сложен, он включает бессоюзную и сочинительную (замыкающую) связь. Между 3 и 4 перечислительные однородные отношения, а между (3, 4) и 5 **соединительные и условно-следственные.** Для их выражения дополнительно к союзу И  используется **тире вместо запятой** (как более сильный знак) и увеличенная пауза в устной речи.

Answer (score 1):

Пример, который Вы приводите, представляет из себя сложную синтаксическую конструкцию. Сложная синтаксическая конструкция – это сложное предложение, части которого соединены разными видами синтаксической связи: сочинительной, подчинительной и бессоюзной.

В зависимости от комбинирования типов синтаксической связи различают сложные синтаксические конструкции с сочинительной и подчинительной связью; с подчинительной и бессоюзной связью; с сочинительной и бессоюзной связью; **с сочинительной, подчинительной и бессоюзной связью.**

В вашем примере как раз представлены  три вида связи: сочинение, подчинение, бессоюзие. Такие предложения распространены в художественной литературе.

Ср.:  **Тем преимуществом особым при жизни автор наделен: все слышит сам, но, как за гробом, уже сказать не может он, какой бы ни был суд нелестный. (Твард.)**

**Но река величаво несет свою воду, и какое ей дело до этих вьюнков: крутясь, плывут они вместе с водой, как недавно плыли льдины (Пришв.).**

Ср. предложения, в которых представлены два вида связи: бессоюзие и подчинение **[Печален я]: [со мною друга Нет], (с кем долгую запил бы я разлуку), (кому бы мог пожать от сердца руку и пожелать весёлых много лет) (А. Пушкин).**

Comment: Мой вопрос касается именно нетипичной модели связи, которая используется в моём примере. Ваш ответ касается сложных синтаксических конструкций в целом, в качестве примеров вы приводите тривиальные модели. Мой вопрос о другом.

Comment: Вы спрашивали: возможно ли такое соединение. Я вам привел примеры. Внимательно читайте!

Answer (score 1):

Не согласна с Вашим разбором, здесь пять простых предложений.

*[1.Но учти]: [2.они ... постоянно меняются], (3.так что держи ухо востро), (4.следи за трендами) — и [5.тогда ты как специалист будешь всегда в цене].*

1 и 2 предложения соединены бессоюзно, 2 - главное для придаточных следствия 3 и 4, соединённых однородной связью, тире стоит перед предложением, содержащим неожиданное присоединение и связанным с предыдущим сложноподчинённым предложением сочинительной связью.

[Но   =  ] :{ [- = ] , (так что ), (  )} — и [ - =].

Вполне корректная конструкция.

Comment: @ Людмила, а  что означают фигурные скобки? Для чего они?

Comment: Автор вопроса указал с их помощью на общность 1 и 2 предикативных частей, а я показала своё несогласие с этим, потому что скобки оторвали придаточные от главного, если указывать какую-то сложную конструкцию, то только  сложноподч. предложение с 2 придаточными, вот я и выделила его с помощью фигурных скобок, а так они не нужны.

Comment: 1. Почему вы не считаете "держи ухо востро" и "следи за трендами" однородными сказуемыми? 2. В вашем случае получается: "Учти, что держи ухо востро, учти, что следи за трендами", т.е. части 2, 3, 4, 5 все поясняют первую часть.

Comment: В односоставном предложении столько предикативных частей, сколько в нём сказуемых, за исключением случаев, когда есть общий зависимый компонент. Например:
Я обиделся и не захотел ему отвечать — простое двусоставное предложение с однородными сказуемыми.
Мне стало обидно и не захотелось ему отвечать — сложное предложение.
Мне стало грустно и одиноко — простое односоставное (безличное) предложение с однородными частями сказуемого, т.к. есть общая часть сказуемого стало .

Comment: 1 связано только с 2:учти: они меняются; 2 с 3 и 4: они меняются, так что держи ухо востро, (так что) следи за трендами. В школьной и довузовской практике ряд односоставных предложений не считается однородными членами, если нет общей части сказуемого или общего зависимого слова, а в вузовской их называют по-разному, часто неполными с нулевым подлежащим, там разные мнения.

Comment: Вернее, первое простое предложение связано бессоюзно с СПП

Comment: @Людмила "Мне стало обидно и не захотелось ему отвечать — сложное предложение" — здесь есть общее зависимое слово "мне", значит, по-вашему, в предложении однородные члены.

Comment: @Людмила "Вернее, первое простое предложение связано бессоюзно с СПП". Так вот именно, что 3, 4 и 5 не поясняют слово "учти", а являются придаточными к части 1, или к блоку 1+2. Иными словами, если мы трансформируем бессоюзную связь в союзную, у нас получится: "Но учти, что они постоянно меняются, так что держи ухо востро, следи за трендами — и тогда ты как специалист будешь всегда в цене". И придаточное следствия с союзом "так что" относится к главному предложению "но учти".

Comment: Мне стало обидно и не захотелось ему отвечать — сложное предложение - это не моё мнение, это из учебника пример автора. Для безличных предложений действует только общая часть сказуемых (мне стало грустно и (стало)одиноко), тогда они однородные, это уже я объединила все односоставные.

Comment: Если что-то трансформировать, то будет уже другая конструкция - СПП, но придаточное следствия там будет относиться не к "ты учти", а к "они  меняются". Смысл: Ты учти, что они меняются, а раз меняются, то держи ухо востро и следи за трендами. Вы некорректно привязываете 1 предложение ко всей конструкции. Учесть нужно только то, что они меняются. Бессоюзная связь между 1 предложением и главным в  СПП (блок простых 2,3,4).

Comment: @Людмила Разве бессоюзная связь не относится ко всем последующим предложением, или это только если они соединены союзно и бессоюзно, то есть не имеет место подчинение?

Comment: Всякий раз по-разному, нужно смотреть на смысл, бывает, что бессоюзно соединены простые предложения, бывает - СПП и ССП. Вот здесь первое простое с СПП,